# Unable to access tmux session through php (shell_exec)

Tags: php, ubuntu, tmux

I created a tmux session on a Ubuntu Server 18.04. In order to give multiple linux users access to the same session I followed these
[instructions.](https://www.howtoforge.com/sharing-terminal-sessions-with-tmux-and-screen) Everything works fine when I'm trying to access the tmux socket/session from "regular" users over the command line.

I'm about to script a website on which I want to start or kill this session. Like in the tutorial provided above, I added the www-data user to the group which shares the tmux socket. In order to execute this tmux commands over php as superuser I added this line `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/tmux` to the visudo file.

When I want to kill the already running session with php(shell_exec) it says:

> "no server running on watten_tmux_socket".

Although I am able to kill this session with the same command as a "regular" user. Whats wrong here?

```
sudo tmux -S /tmp/watten_tmux_socket kill-session -t WattenServer
```

**EDIT**: Starting a session on a socket over php doesn't work either. No session and no socket gets created under /tmp, while in the command line it works.

Comment: I can only think this is a very bad idea (`su` or root level access by the `www` user). If there is ever an exploit in PHP or some insecure code points, that would allow someone to exec their own PHP, your server would be owned in no time. Do not do this. Login over `ssh` and `kill` the session if need. Do NOT elevate the `www` user to allow `su` or root level access.

Comment: Such php commands are being executed only after a secure login window. Also when the website will be finished, the visudo line above will be replaced with something like www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /my/script so that www-data has just access to my script. This is just for developing purpouse.

Comment: If you use systemd to start your php server, check if you have `PrivateTmp=true` in the Unit file, as this means `/tmp` is in its own namespace. Note, if you want a vt100-like terminal in a web page check out anyterm, ajaxterm, wetty, shellinabox and gateone amongst others.

Comment: I don't use systemd to start php. I'am able to access the /tmp folder and the Tmux-socket in it, the problem is that executing the command with php says: no server on this socket, but when executing the same command in the commandline i can easily access, start or kill a session. Btw i don't want a vt100 like terminal, i just want to start a new session an execute a command in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i did a workaround. Using sudo in PHP is very insecure so now when i want to start or kill a new tmux session over php i modify the content of a txt file (something like serverstate:on). I installed incron `apt-get install incron`. With the help of the incrontab you can register some sort events whenever a file changes. So now whenever i modify the content of this file, a script gets executed wich starts or kills the tmux session.

Reference: [Incron tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/trigger-commands-on-file-or-directory-changes-with-incron/)